# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient installed with ClickOnce and Windows Installer

Tags: windows, installation, clickonce

I have a C# project that is using Entity Framework with LocalDb and thus Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

When the application is installed with ClickOnce everything works fine.

Then I created an Installer Project and added the Publish Items in the application folder as it is suggested for a Core application. Using the Windows Installer setup, when the application runs, I am getting the error: `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.`

The problem is that I need to set some registry values therefore I have to use the Windows Installer instead of the ClickOnce deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when in the Installer project I replaced the shortcut to the executable with a shortcut to the application's project Published Items.